# one child to set parent width, one to wrap

Tags: html, css

Given two divs in a parent how do I allow one to define the parent width and force the other to wrap? I'm open to solutions involving tables or js, but not excited about them.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="header">This should not wrap</div>
<div class="text">This should wrap to the header's width. This should not cause the parent to grow.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.header {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.text {
    /*what goes here?*/
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DtTPg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="header">This should not wrap</div>
    <div class="text">This should wrap to the header's width. This should not cause the parent to grow.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.parent > .header {
    width: auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.text').width($('.header').width());
});
```

I used a bit of jQuery to set the width of the `.text` class to become the same width as the `.header` class. Prior to that, I set the width of the `.parent` to become the width of the `.header` using the above CSS code.

**[DEMO JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DtTPg/2/)**

Comment: BuddhistBeast, I've adapted this solution to my needs. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You got it! Glad to be able to help out!